# Wordpress blog posts permalinks giving 404 on nginx

Tags: permalinks, nginx

I have the following nginx configuration to serve blog on `/blog/` URL.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.in www.example.in;
        root /var/www/website;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        # Serve blog
        location /blog {
                return 301 /blog/;
        }

        location /blog/ {
                autoindex on;
                alias /var/www/blog/;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                }
        }

        # Serve other files
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

The homepage is working fine at `https://example.in/blog` and also the admin panel is working perfectly `https://example.in/blog/wp-admin/`

When the blog posts permalink is set to plain, the blogs posts are opening fine with the URL

```
https://example.in/blog/?p=123
```

But on changing the permalink to another format `blog/blog/2021/04/16/sample-post/`, It is giving 404

```
https://example.in/blog/blog/2021/04/16/sample-post/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `^~` prefix on the `location` statement, change the `alias` statement to `root /var/www;`, and change the last parameter of the `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
location ^~ /blog/ {
    autoindex on;
    root /var/www;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```